# How to encrypt extremely small pieces of data (2 - 4 bytes)?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm developing a medical device that operates under extreme low-power constraints and transmits data with BLE, where every unnecessary millisecond of air time matters. I am developing a Beacon advertising protocol where sensor data is encoded directly into the advertising packet. The data I need to transmit is very simple and small, occupying only two to four total bytes. I would like to encrypt these 2-4 bytes before adding them to the advertising packet, to be decrypted by the receiving smartphone after being pulled out of the advertising packet. I'd like to keep the encrypted data as small as possible, whereas I know many algorithms create set length strings (20+ bytes).

I am currently transmitting these 2-4 bytes as hexadecimal values, to be interpreted as integer values by the receiving smartphone application. I am not overly experienced with cryptography or encryption methods, but do know that most algorithms operate on larger pieces of data. Are there any algorithms or protocols that would be appropriate for such small pieces of data? Should I "roll my own" protocol for encryption since this may be a special case?

Comment: This is probably more suited for [crypto.se] instead.

Comment: It's a bit of a vague question.  A lot may depend on how private/sensitive the data is, whether you can rely on previous transmissions having been received (_e.g._ maintaining state for encrypting across multiple packets), whether negotiation is required (_e.g._ symmetric _vs_ asymmetric), _etc_.  To begin with, consider just using a simple replacement cipher using a known table of byte values.  You can even use different seeds into the table for successive bytes in the same transmission if you like.  In the end, only you know your requirements.

Comment: This isn't really a C question, but a crypto question, so the site linked by Ken White should be better equipped to help you. That said, encryption isn't enough to protect sensitive data. It's part of a large solution that ensures you are communicating with the intended party. I'm not sure you provided enough data to provide an answer that factors that in. Consider that when you take your question over there.

Comment: Encrypting two bytes at a time with solid modern ciphers is not a problem. For example, if you wanted to encrypt a stream of these two bytes, you would use a cipher in CFB or OFB [mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) to generate a stream which is XORed with your data rather than using the cipher in CBC mode (which requires a full block before you can start encrypting). **Do not roll out your protocol.** The exact solution depends on the many factors paddy mentioned.

Comment: Crypto is very hard. I'm glad you're reaching out for help.

Comment: Fantastic responses, thank you very much! As you can tell, this is my first post on stack overflow (have lurked for far too long), so did not think about posting direct to Ken White's suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @exitfailure I would use a stream cipher like AES in GCM mode or ChaCha20.

Comment: To be honest, I think you need consultancy rather than an algorithm. Otherwise your question will probably not contain enough information to be answerable in the first place (just a friendly tip from a mod at https://crypto.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Cryptography Stack Exchange.